# area51 recent history not showing reputation gains from users following a proposal

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, area-51, recent-activity

The recent activity history (available from clicking on the envelope) isn't showing reputation gains from users following a proposal.  I've seen my reputation grow +15 from 3 users following a proposal I own but that reputation increase isn't showing in my history.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is a duplicate.

Comment: @Chris, I looked but did not find.

Comment: I have seen this problem too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been implemented.